# x265: Why do P and B frames have different encoding time?

Tags: video, encoding, video-encoding, hevc, libx265

I'm using x265 encoder for HEVC.

I have 3 different configurations. Have

1. 4 B frames (B4)
2. 2 B frames (B2)
3. 0 B frames (B0 - all P frames)

Their encoding times are different.

B4 and B2 need much less encoding time than B0 that contains only P frames. Do you have any idea why?

Both P and B frames have equal QP using parameter `--pbratio 1.0`.

You can see the three different output files here using QP 36: [B4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CFx75Ro7vGaG1ZUkJ3bHpYbFk/view?usp=sharing), [B2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CFx75Ro7vGTU95by15bnV6N1k/view?usp=sharing) and [B0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CFx75Ro7vGOW1VN1NESGJiTWs/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Do you repeatedly get these differences?

Comment: @damjeux Yes! In addition, I tried the same in HM 15.0 reference software and got the inverse results...

Comment: Yes, you would expect the B-frames to take longer because of the bidirectional prediction. And I see your B-frames have up to 3 reference frames [L0] and [L1], whereas the P-frames have only 1 reference frame [L0]...

Comment: @damjeux Yes, exactly. Although, using x265 I get the inverse situation and I' don't know the reason.

Comment: Have you tried with the [libde265](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265) encoder?

Comment: @PieterMeiresone No I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that encoding B-frames is simpler because interpolating is simpler then extrapolating (as in the case of P-frames). Interpolating tends to give smaller errors then extrapolating, which reduces the amount of bits that needs to be encoded.

[image]

As for the results using the HM 15.0 reference software, this is reference software so performance is not the main priority. Quote from the [HM software manual](https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/trunk/doc/software-manual.pdf):

> It is not meant to be a particularly efficient implementation of anything, and one may notice its apparent unsuitability for a particular use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This could be a possible explanation and since there are not many HEVC encoders available we don't have further comparisons. But can we justify the result for example in a journal paper using this argue as a justification?

Comment: I think "simpler" is not correct here. If you look at the motion estimation (ME), B-frames require to run the ME on at least 2 frames, while P-frames require only to run the ME on 1 frame. And ME is one of the most computationally complex parts of the encoder. The graph above might give an intuition why you need less bits for B-frames, but not why you need less time. You would need to look at the time spent on entropy encoding in both cases, to see if there is a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

With the development of HEVC, B frames became more popular for general use and basically replaced P frames in all use cases.

My expectation is simply that the x265 developers just spend more time and effort on optimizing the fast coding algorithms of B pictures, because these are used in the default configuration.

Although HM uses some shortcuts, the encoding time basically increases linearly with the number of reference pictures.